# Retrieving OKTA Attributes in Spring Application Hosted on WebSphere with OIDC Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openid, okta, okta-api

I am having a spring boot based application which uses spring security and spring boot dependencies

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.okta</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-spring-security-roles-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>okta-spring-security-roles-example</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <okta.version>1.2.1</okta.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${okta.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <!-- Required for any libraries that expect to call the commons logging APIs -->
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

homecontroller.java

```
package com.okta.okta.spring.example.controller;

/*
Copyright 2018 Okta, Inc.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.security.Principal;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Principal principal) {
        if (principal != null) {
            return "redirect:" + SecureController.AUTHENTICATED_PATH;
        }
        return "home";
    }
}
```

secureController.java

```
package com.okta.okta.spring.example.controller;

/*
Copyright 2018 Okta, Inc.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.xml.ws.spi.http.HttpContext;
import java.security.Principal;

@Controller
public class SecureController {

    public static final String AUTHENTICATED_PATH = "/authenticated";

    @RequestMapping(AUTHENTICATED_PATH)
    public String authenticated(HttpServletRequest req) {
        Object user =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        Principal principal = req.getUserPrincipal();

        return "authenticated";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('users')")
    public String users() {
        return "roles";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admins")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admins')")
    public String admins() {
        return "roles";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/403")
    public String error403() {
        return "403";
    }
}
```

application.yml file

```
okta:
  oauth2:
    baseUrl: https://dev-xxxxx.okta.com
    issuer: https://dev-xxxxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default
    clientId: 0XXXXXXXXXXXXXX7
    clientSecret: HXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXZ
    audience: api://default
    groupsClaim: groups
    postLogoutRedirectUri: http://localhost:8080
```

In secureController.java class I am able to retrieve the user object using this code snippet
       `Object user =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

I am able to see OKTA attributes in the debugger

[image: okta attributes]

when I did login to the application on localhost://8080 I am able to login using OKTA authentication and I am able to see OKTA attributes in the debugger as shown in the above image

Note: I am using OKTA sandbox account for spring boot application. This is working as expected. Here OKTA properties are added in application.yml.  I registered this application in my OKTA account

---

Now I am having a spring based application which is configured with OKTA and the OKTA URL is specific to my organization.  The OKTA is configured using  WebSphere application server. like below
By adding okta client ID like below screen shot. My pom.xml uses spring security dependency.

[image: okta using ODIC setup]

When I run the spring based on localhost:9080/abc  I am able to login to the application successfully using my OKTA organization account

The screen shot shows OIDC stetup using relying party. OIDC is configured using OKTA.  Using this configuration I am able to login successfully login to the application

I am trying retreive the OKTA attribites same as I did for spring boot application like sub, at_hash, email same as screen shot 1 for spring boot application

The controller class I am using is HomeController.java and code for controller is
[image: spring app controller class]

I am able to login and when I try to get security context holder
`SecurityContextHolder.getContext();`   The object I am getting NULL.

My application's configuration is set up in the WebSphere console, and it successfully authenticates users. However, I'm unable to retrieve OKTA attributes as I can in a Spring Boot application.

Is there a specific configuration or approach I'm missing to access OKTA attributes in a Spring application hosted on WebSphere with OIDC setup? How can I correctly retrieve these attributes?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Note: Spring application uses Organization OKTA account which is specific to organization

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).